# Page redirect to 404 when set Permalink = "Post Name"

Tags: permalinks, 404-error, iis

In My wordpress site When I set Permalink structure as Post Name , It redirects all posts to 404.  With Default permalink , It works fine.

**Server Details :**

Windows Server - IIS

**Web.Config Code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="WordPress Rule" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have just got help from here : https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

But that code is not working for me.  Should I need to modify any other file as well to solve 404 error?

Comment: Hi, What is your IIS version.

Comment: In PHP info it is showing me Microsoft-IIS/8.0 , is that correct version?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue you are having is that the URL you have in your match tag, `<match url=".*" />` needs to be `url="*"`. Notice the absence of the dot. Currently your rule is only matching on URLs that end with an extension, like `index.php`, `blog.html`, `background.jpg`, etc. Removing the dot should allow it to match all URLs.

Comment: I've notice a ton of example versions with each of those options, and have been trying to figure out the difference.  Thank you!